# How to copy files from mobile connected with PC through USB port in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to copy files from android mobile which is connected to PC through USB port.
This code is working for copy files from one folder to anther in PC. But when i try to copy from mobile it show "Path Not Found" MessageBox.
Please help me for this problem.

```
if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(@"This PC\M Hassan\Phone\Lec\Android\Mid"))
            {
                string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"This PC\M Hassan\Phone\Lec\Android\Mid");

                // Copy the files and overwrite destination files if they already exist. 
                foreach (string s in files)
                {
                    // Use static Path methods to extract only the file name from the path.
                    fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(s);
                    destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(destFolder, fileName);
                    System.IO.File.Copy(s, destFile, true);
                }

                MessageBox.Show("Successfully Configured.", "Done", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Path Not Found.", "Field Required", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

            }
```

Comment: had you browse "This PC\M Hassan\Phone\Lec\Android\Mid", is this exist in your PC?

Comment: yes this is real path of my mobile which is connected with PC, i have browse it

Comment: I don't thing there is a folder `This PC` on the start path of the application you try to test. The name `This PC` is only a user friendly name that signalises, that this path is not a remote path. The `M Hassan` is probably name of the disk or device. This path is not used in file operations. There you need to use `C:\` to select _first_ hard drive. You can not use the text from _Windows Explorer_ as paths, that you should use in your application.

Comment: "This PC\M Hassan\Phone\Lec\Android\Mid" is path of folder exists in my mobile, when i connect with PC through USB port is shows same path for Mid folder. "This PC" is my computer name.

Comment: Sorry but that's not a valid Windows path string. All paths which Windows recognises either start with a drive letter (e.g. C:\folder\file.txt) or are in UNC format e.g. (\\server\share\file.txt).See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists(v=vs.110).aspx . The only exception might be if this path happens to be relative to the current working directory, but I doubt this since it's unlikely to be relative to your app path,  since it can't mount the mobile filesystem as part of C:\

Comment: I have to copy from mobile which is obviously not a part of PC, that will treat as peripheral device, is it possible to copy data by windows based application.

Comment: yes it should be, if the mobile connects to the PC and its filesystem is mapped as a drive or UNC path. You just need to get the right path.

Comment: i am trying to do but i found this path which is not mapped as drive , please help me how to get correct path.

Comment: It depends on the phone and how precisely it connects. But you seem to have just copied that string from your windows explorer bar, which generally gives a user-friendly representation by default. If you click on an empty part of the address bar, it usually switches to the actual path. e.g. if I go to "Libraries > Documents > My Documents" and then click on the address bar, just to the right of the word Documents it turns into "C:\users\adyson\Documents", which is the real path to that folder. Same with a network device or a mapped drive.

Comment: See also https://www.howtogeek.com/121218/beginner-how-to-make-explorer-always-show-the-full-path-in-windows-8/ . It's the same in Windows 7 as well, not sure about 10.